# History -a from a bash script

Tags: bash, history

I'm trying to call the following within a bash script:

```
`history -a current_history`
```

it is supposed to create the file with the commands executed this session.

Works perfectly fine in a shell environment

Does not work within a bash script

I see information which shows that you must call history differently within a bash script, as the following format:

```
#!/bin/bash

HISTFILE=~/.bash_history  # Set the history file.
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '   # Set the hitory time format.
set -o history            # Enable the history.
file="/media/saleel_almajd/Study/linux/my_scripts/history.txt"
history >> $file          # Save the history.
```

but in doing so when modifying the last line to `history -a`.

this then returns no results when compared to the regularly called `history -a` file.

Comment: `history -a ~/current_history`

Comment: doesnt work @dlin

Comment: as i have said above, that command works fine OUTSIDE of a bash script, when it executed within a bash script it does not work. 4.15.0-99-generic @dlin

Comment: What session's history do you want? The shell that is running the script, or the parent shell from which you executed the script?

Comment: im not quite sure i understand what you mean, I want it to show the history of the current user, as it shows when calling the command natively via the shell @terdon

Comment: @throwaway56786897 so you want everything that is in the original `HISTFILE`? Otherwise, you will get the history of only the commands run in your script.

Comment: @terdon no, the histfile contains ALL commands. I need the list which is contained within history -a, this needs to be obtained from within a bash script

Comment: This is starting to feel like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). Please [edit] your question and explain what your actual objective is. Why do you want a script for this? How will you use it? I suspect a script just isn't the right tool and you probably want a function or an alias, but I need to understand what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107460/discussion-between-terdon-and-throwaway56786897).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.` dot or `source` before your script name, so it will be executed in the current shell:

```
$ . hist.sh

$ cat hist.sh 
history -a current_history

$ cat current_history 
cat curhist 
ls
rm cur*
ls
rm '\'
cat '\'
cd test
ls
rm current_history 
vim.tiny hist.sh 
. hist.sh
```

This will place your current shell history into `current_history` file you've specified.

```
$ source --help
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
```

If you want to save timestamps, you could try the next script:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%c '
history -a current_history
paste -sd '#\n' current_history | awk -F"#" '{d=$2 ; $2="";print NR"\t"strftime("%d/%m/%y %T",d)"\t"$0}' > formatted_history
```

Comment: $HISTFILE slows all commands, not current commands when called for as: history -a current_history @Gryu

Comment: @throwaway56786897 does sourcing work for you? It is for current session. If you don't need $HISTFILE, just don't use it. No one requires it.

Comment: after testing sourcing the .sh file works but, removes the formating from the command execution time & date provided by HITTIMEFORMAT @Gryu

Comment: @throwaway56786897 it's not sourcing removes timestamps, but `history -a somefile` command does not take any attention to that variable)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the commands that were executed by your script inot a file using `history -a`, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o history            # Enable the history.
## Now set the HISTFILE to what you want
HISTFILE="/media/saleel_almajd/Study/linux/my_scripts/history.txt"
history -a                # write it to your file
```

This will result in the following being written to `/media/saleel_almajd/Study/linux/my_scripts/history.txt`:

```
$ cat /media/saleel_almajd/Study/linux/my_scripts/history.txt
## Now set the HISTFILE to what you want
HISTFILE="/media/saleel_almajd/Study/linux/my_scripts/history.txt"
history -a                # write it to your file
```

The `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable is irrelevant. That is only used when the history file is read, not when it is printed to. You can still use it to see the history you printed. Just run this:

```
$ history -c  ## clear the current history
$ HISTFILE="/media/saleel_almajd/Study/linux/my_scripts/history.txt"
$ history -r  ## read the new one
$ HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T ' history
    1  2020-05-01 14:18:53 HISTFILE="/media/saleel_almajd/Study/linux/my_scripts/history.txt"
    2  2020-05-01 14:19:01 history -r
    3  2020-05-01 14:19:01 ## Now set the HISTFILE to what you want
    4  2020-05-01 14:19:01 HISTFILE="/media/saleel_almajd/Study/linux/my_scripts/history.txt"
    5  2020-05-01 14:19:01 history -a                # write it to your file
    6  2020-05-01 14:19:03 HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T ' history
```

Comment: im sorry, i dont understand where you got this from, i appreciate your effort. But i need a copy from the CURRENT session. Not from the script, not from the the total history list. History -a shows the current commands from your session, not total

Comment: @throwaway56786897 no, history -a simply _appends_ the commands of the current session. But if you run it in a script, the current session is the session running the script, scripts always run in their own shell instance. That's why I keep trying to get you to explain exactly what "session" you are referring to. I now think you want the history of the script's parent shell, of whatever shell you were in when you ran the script. Is that right? If so, why would you do this in a script instead of a function?

Answer (score 0):

In bash, to item "history -a" not working in a script, I can contribute some details.

Now I am using Kubuntu 22.04, but I suffer from this issue since many years.

1.

The script must be sourced (otherwise another .bah_history file is used but not that of the current shell). Then "history -a" does work normally -- with followig exception:

2.

In many such scripts, often before of "history -a" these two commands are used:

history -c

history -r

And of these two, it is

history -c

that causes the non-working of "history -a". Nothimg is written to .bah-history file.

regards

antondhidhdih